# Files: slow mounting causes file display problem

Tags: pantheon-files, audio-cd

I've tried to play several audio disks. It works, audacious plays songs without a problem. Only when I open an audio disk in Files, it only shows 6 tracks there, although there are more. Running the command
`ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/cdda\:host\=sr0/` reveals all the rest. I can play these "hidden" songs using a terminal command.

What's wrong with the Files and how to fix it?

**UPD**

For some reason when you mount a CD and open this newly generated gvfs without much waiting, Files shows only 6 tracks, but then, when you simply refresh everything appears. Or when you instead of opening the drive directly (initiating mounting and opening without any pause in between), select to mount and wait for it, you won't face this problem.

Not a critical bug at all. However, that was totally unexpected even though I've been using Linux for years already. Breaks UX significantly.

Answer (score 0):

A brief investigation indicates that this might be a caching problem: the view displays the tracks of the previously mounted cd initially, at least if they have the same name (e.g. Track 1.wav etc).  So mounting a CD with 13 tracks shows 13 tracks, ejecting and mounting CD with 6 tracks also shows 13 tracks until refreshed. Remounting the 13 track CD then shows 6 tracks until refreshed.  It sounds as if it may be related to this issue:https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/36, but it would be worth raising an separate issue on GitHub